# Read multiple files, dictionary value gets overwritten (Addition of column name)

Tags: python, pandas

When I was reading multiple files and exporting it, I realised that the values on these 4 column got overwritten by the latest value. Every file has the same iat cell location. I will like to know if this can be looped and values not getting overwritten.

```
df= pd.concat(data)
df['name'], df['age'], df['height'], df['address'] = [], [], [], []
for df in df:
    df['name'].append(df.iat[1,1])
    df['age'].append(df.iat[2,1])
    df['height'].append(df.iat[2,2])
    df['address'].append(df.iat[2,3])
     Details = {'Name':name, 'Age':age,'Height':height,'Address':address}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(Details)
```

For example, (1st Data): Name: John Age: 20 Height: 1.7m Address: Bla Bla Bla

(2nd Data): Name: Jack Age: 21 Height: 1.7m Address: Blah Blah Blah

(3rd Data): Name: Jane Age: 20 Height: 1.62m Address: Blah Blah

Comment: Have you worked with `pandas` before? Because each and every line in the code using `pandas` has an error. You may want to google "pandas tutorial" to understand the data structure and how to use it.

Comment: I am not sure how to loop with the column name and it gave me this error: int obj is not subscriptable